# Why the solution is having a negative value, it should be positive as it is a physical quantity

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve 5 non-linear equations simultaneously, so I am using Solve[] function. Here is my code:

```
     gamma = 6.6*10^(-3);
     r = 253*10^(-8);
     lambdaGL = 5047*10^(-10);
     volume = 272.47*10^(-30);
     ziGL = 218*10^(-10);

     k = 1.380648*10^(-23);
     Na = 6.023*10^(23);
     hb = 1.0545718*10^(-34);
     e = 1.6021766*10^(-19);
     vp = 12.56637*10^(-7);

     eq1 = ((1.031222)*(k^2)*m*volume*Na*(n^(1/3)))/(hb^2) == gamma;
     eq2 = (29.60881*(hb^3))/((e^2)*r*(m^2)*(vf^2)) == l;
     eq3 = (0.033773)*((m*vf/hb)^3) == n;
     eq4 = ((m/(vp*n*(e^2)))*((l + zi0)/l)) == (lambdaGL^2);
     eq5 = ((0.906899*zi0)^2)*(l/(l + zi0)) == (ziGL^2);
     Ans = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, {m, n, vf, l, zi0}, Reals]
```

the solution which I am getting is:

```
    {{m -> 4.29454*10^-30, n -> 1.48789*10^26, vf -> 40233.7, 
     l -> 1.79295*10^-8, zi0 -> -1.28254*10^-8}}
```

But here zi0 should be positive, I dont't know what I have done wrong. Please help me.

Comment: You may have a precision issue. I would not advise using `Solve` with expressions containing approximate numbers as input. `FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, 
  eq5}, {{m, 10^-30}, {n, 10^-26}, {vf, 10^4}, {l, .10^-8}, {zi0, 
   10^-8}}]` complains "Machine precision is insufficient to achieve the accuracy ".

Comment: I can't know the domain of this question, but common sense is welcome: is the magnitude of this value of `zi0` effectively zero when interpreted in the real world setting? In addition to precision issues on the actual computation, you may have an issue with precision of numerical constants you use, and that no matter what precision you use, you end up with this sort of residuals from it. I rationalized all these constants and still get essentially same, negative value of `zi0`, which would support this hypothesis.

Comment: Try `eqn = Eliminate[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, {m, n, vf, l}]`. Next get rid of the very high exponents: `eqn = eqn[[1]] /10.^266 == eqn[[2]]/10.^266 // Simplify`. Finally, find your solution for $zi0$:`Solve[eqn && zi0 > 0]`